# JQuery Mobile specifying page id in jQuery(document).on('pageinit'

Tags: jquery, mobile

In my multi-page JQM app I was having issues with events firing multiple times. For example:

```
    $("#Button").on("click", function (event) {

            alert("hello");

    });
```

This would fire once the first time but after navigating to other pages or using back button the number of alert pop-ups increased as the number of visits to the link increased.
I was able to stop this by using

```
event.stopImmediatePropagation();
```

But this was causing another issue in my app. WTF? This is very frustrating. Why is this not better documented on JQM site? .. anyhow. In searching for a solution I found this post at

http://www.ardeearam.com/blog/2012/06/03/jquery-mobile-events-firing-multiple-times/

It recommends to delegate the ‘pageinit’ event to the page id where the element is found. i.e.

```
jQuery(document).on('pageinit', '#page_one', function (event) { 

)};
```

I had a hunch that instead of having multiple pageinit blocks for each block of code for that page (as the article says) to just set the pageinit page id to the first page in the html. I tried it and the multiple event problem disappeared. I tested my app to make sure that nothing else on other pages (I have six total pages) was broken and it worked fine.  My question is: Can anyone see a drawback or problem in using this method for pageinit?

Answer (score 0):

This happens because jQuery Mobile keeps more than one page in the DOM at a time. You have to code with that in mind. if elements with the id `button` exist on two different pages, one of those elements will get the event bound to it multiple times (since id's must be unique)

The delegated `pageinit` approach is the recommended approach.

Comment: Thanks but I did not have the same id in different pages and it still was binding multiple times. My question is specifically asking if delegating pageinit only to first page and including code for other pages in that block is a good practice.

Comment: I would have to see more context, that was just one common example that causes that outcome.